# When to use "started to" and "started to be"

Tags: active-vs-passive

I have a problem regarding to be sentences..

E.g. Which sentence is correct among these two:

1. And in result, 1st movement started to decrease.
2. And in result, 1st movement started to be decreased.

And please explain the reason..
In my view, we should use "started to be decreased" as it is a passive sentence, so why we generally use first one i.e. "started to decrease"?

Similar problem for the following:

Started to scatter?

Or

started to be scattered?

I m so confused..

Comment: Did you write the example sentences?

Comment: Not related to your question, but you are almost certainly missing some articles. It's hard to be certain without the context, but you almost certainly want _the first movement_, and probably also _in the result_.  But I suspect these are not the only problems. "Movement" seems an unlikely word here, and probably _as a result_ or perhaps _in the results_. Again, I can't be sure without more context.

Answer (score 2):

"Decrease" and "scatter" are both **"unaccusative verbs,"** meaning that (among other things) they have similar meanings in the active and passive voice. In general:

1. The passive voice ("the particles were scattered") suggests that some specific external agent caused the action. You can specify that agent using "by": "The particles were scattered *by the wind.*" The same is true if you use it as an active transitive verb: "The wind scattered the particles." The intransitive usage in the active voice, meanwhile, does not suggest such an external cause: "The ants scattered to find food."
2. If you can use either the active or the passive voice equally well in a given situation, you should use the active; it's generally considered simpler and more idiomatic to do so.

Answer (score 0):

This is the difference between active and passive.

This sentence has a main verb "started", and a catentive complement "to scatter..."  The complement is an infinitive clause.

In these sentences, there is an actor (the person that does the action) and a patient (the thing that is acted upon)

> I started to scatter the seeds.

This is active.  The subject "I" is the actor and the seeds (object) is the patient.  The seeds are the things that I scatter.

> The seeds started to be scattered.

This is passive. The passive voice is in the infinitive  so "to be scattered".  The subject "The seeds" is now the patient (the seeds are the things that someone scatters) and the actor is not mentioned.

You use "start to do" to make an active voice sentence, and "start to be done" for a passive voice sentence.  In most cases you should use the active voice. The passive voice should be used when you can't mention the actor.

Your other example (1st movement started to decrease) is unclear.  Does "1st movement" refer to a piece of music?

Comment: I am studying gender studies subject, so in the aftermath of 1st wave of feminism there is a concept , i e., when they lost the unified goal, so in result 1st movement started to be reduced/decreased/diminished ,  until the second wave started in 1960s..     so here i will use which one? In result, movement started to be decreased or in result, movement started to decrease?

Comment: Not "in result", but perhaps "As a result",  and I'd just use "the first wave started to diminish"  There is no actor that is causing them to diminish. This uses a labile sense of the verb as described in the other answer.

Comment: If i write this, i.e., as a result , it started to be diminished? Will it be wrong ?